# can we set particular time in java

Tags: java, calendar

i want to start a scheduler daily once from my project which can get some dates and time of the same day from DB and again start some schedulers of tomes get from DB to do certain task. i am trying to set time but it not set that time , instead add that time in date so they execute lateral time. following example code.

```
   Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
   date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
   date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 56);
   date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

what it set time 00:56:00 of 24 sep 2016 instead of 12:56:00 of 23 sep 2016.

it add the time given instead of set that time.
Please help me and tell me the method to set time instead adding time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the Javadoc on `HOUR` and compare with `HOUR_OF_DAY`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Why does the `Date` change to `24 Sep`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Because the time is set to 12PM plus some minites so it's beyond midnight at the end of that day.

Comment: @Marko, if we go with JavDocs it clearly explains tha Calendar.HOUR works as :Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the morning or afternoon. HOUR is used for the 12-hour clock (0 - 11). Noon and midnight are represented by 0, not by 12

Comment: so if we have to set as noon we should do as date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);

Comment: @mhasan seems like a java bug then

Comment: Yup there issues with using java.util.Calendar :)

Comment: @mhasan If we go with Javadocs, it clearly explains that `When a Calendar is in lenient mode, it accepts a wider range of calendar field values than it produces. When a Calendar recomputes calendar field values for return by get(), all of the calendar fields are normalized. For example, a lenient GregorianCalendar interprets MONTH == JANUARY, DAY_OF_MONTH == 32 as February 1.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shold use like this:

> ```
>     Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
>     date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
>     date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 56);
>     date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
>     System.out.println(date.getTime());
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
```

use this

```
date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
```